# Find a String from one ArrayList as a Charsequence of another ArrayList String in Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist

My Java routine should find a `String` from one `ArrayList` as a `char` sequence of another `ArrayList` `String`.

If I search for a `String` item from the source `ArrayList` in the target `ArrayList` it works. 
If the target `ArrayList` item has more alphanumeric literals I tried to find the wanted part by using a `char` sequence.

Short Example in Words:

> ArrayList_A Items: "A0B","C1D","E2F"
>   ArrayList_B Item: "A0B"

Result: Item B found in `ArrayList_A` Items (works)

> ArrayList_A Items: "A0B/C1D","E2F"
>   ArrayList_B Item: "A0B"

Result: Item B found in `ArrayList_A` Items (this is what I want additionally)

Below is my partly working code. Can anyone please fix it so that I can learn from the solution?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Checking {

    static void checkValues () {

        ArrayList<String> arrayListA = new ArrayList();
        arrayListA.add("A0B/C1D");
        arrayListA.add("E2F");
        System.out.println("\narrayListA: " + arrayListA);
        int sizeLA = arrayListA.size();
        System.out.println("arrayListA Length:" + sizeLA);

        ArrayList<String> arrayListB = new ArrayList();
        arrayListB.add("A0B");
        arrayListB.add("E2F");
        System.out.println("\narrayListB: " + arrayListB);
        int sizeLB = arrayListB.size();
        System.out.println("arrayListB Length:" + sizeLB);

        ArrayList<String> arrayListFound = new ArrayList();

        //Something must be fixed here...
        arrayListB.stream().forEach((searchStr) -> {
            System.out.print("\nstr Search Item is: " + searchStr);
            if(arrayListA.contains((CharSequence)searchStr)){
                System.out.print(" - found!" );
                arrayListFound.add((String) searchStr);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" - not found");
            }
        });

        System.out.println("\n\narrayListFound Items: " + arrayListFound);
        int sizeListFound = arrayListFound.size();  
        System.out.println("sizeListFound Length :" + sizeListFound);   
        System.out.println("Expected to be fully found in arrayListFound: " + arrayListB); 
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkValues();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should use functional style programming. forEach() doesn't allow you more than standard for (...)

For exact matching

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListFound = arrayListB.stream()
          .filter(arrayListA::contains)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For substring matcing

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListFound = arrayListB.stream()
          .filter(itemB -> arrayListA.stream()
                 .matchAny(itemA -> itemA.contains(itemB))
           )
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I wanted to add this but since you did +1

Answer (score 2):

You may stream over both collections and use `String#contains` instead of `List#contains`.

It will add all the corresponding `String` objects from `B` contained in `A` to `arrayListFound`

```
arrayListB.stream().forEach(b ->
    arrayListA.stream().forEach(a -> {
        if (a.contains(b)){
            arrayListFound.add(b);
        }
    }
));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody that contributed. Now I understand and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(arrayListA.contains((CharSequence)searchStr)){
    System.out.print(" - found!" );
    arrayListFound.add((String) searchStr);
}
```

This snippet says, "if my list contains exactly this string, it's found". But your String `A0B`, isn't the same as `A0B/C1D`. Iterating over both lists and checking the `contains` method of `String` and not of `ArrayList`, you'll find what you need. E.g:

```
arrayListB.stream().forEach((searchStr) -> {
    System.out.print("\nstr Search Item is: " + searchStr);
    arrayListA.stream().forEach((sndStr) -> {
        if (sndStr.contains(searchStr) || searchStr.contains(sndStr)) {
            System.out.print(" - found!");
            arrayListFound.add((String) searchStr);
        } else {
            System.out.print(" - not found");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that only slightly modifies your implementation is as follows.

```
arrayListB.stream().forEach((searchStr) -> {
    if(arrayListA.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.contains((CharSequence)searchStr))){
        System.out.print(" - found!" );
        arrayListFound.add((String) searchStr);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(" - not found");
    }
});
```

i. We can use `anyMatch` which would be perform better than `foreach`.

ii. Here we are checking if there exists any string in `arrayListA` which would have searchStr from `arrayListB` as the sub-string.

To do it in purely functional style without mutating the `arrayListFound` list, the following approach can be adopted:

```
Predicate<String> isInArrayA = searchStr-> arrayListA.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.contains(searchStr));
arrayListFound = (ArrayList<String>) arrayListB.stream()
                .filter(isInArrayA)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```